# clearing a dictionary but keeping the keys

Tags: python

Is it possible to clear all the entries within a dictionary but keep all the keys?

For example if I had:

```
my_dic={
        "colour":[],
        "number":[]
        }
```

I put some stuff in them:

```
my_dic["colour"]='Red'
my_dic["number"]='2'
```

I can clear these by:

```
my_dic["colour"] = []
my_dic["number"] = []
```

But this is long winded if I want to clear a large dictionary quickly, is there a quicker way perhaps using for?  I want to keep the keys `["colour"], ["number"]`, without having to recreate them, just clear all the entries within them.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The original dictionary.  So any data I added later on is removed, and I have the original dictionary with the keys created but no entries within them.

Comment: Are all the values lists? Do you want to replace the lists with new empty lists, or truncate the lists so that the change would propagate to other references to that list? Is it necessary to keep the same dict object, or can that object simply be replaced with a new empty dict?

Comment: You are not putting some stuff in 'them', you are *replacing* your empty lists with other values. You'd use `my_dic["colour"].append('Red')` to add values to the lists. If you are using list objects as 'empty values', I'd use `None` instead of an empty list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply clear all lists in a loop:

```
for value in my_dic.values():
    del value[:]
```

Note the `value[:]` slice deletion; we are removing all *indices* in the list, not the `value` reference itself.

Note that if you are using Python 2 you probably want to use `my_dic.itervalues()` instead of `my_dic.values()` to avoid creating a new list object for the loop.

Demo:

```
>>> my_dic = {'colour': ['foo', 'bar'], 'number': [42, 81]}
>>> for value in my_dic.values():
...     del value[:]
...
>>> my_dic
{'colour': [], 'number': []}
```

You could also replace all values with new empty lists:

```
my_dic.update((key, []) for key in my_dic)
```

or replace the whole dictionary entirely:

```
my_dic = {key: [] for key in my_dic}
```

Take into account these two approaches will not update other references to either the lists (first approach) or the whole dictionary (second approach).

Comment: Or: `my_dic.update((k, []) for k in my_dic)` for a one-liner - albeit with slightly different behaviour depending on whether references to the lists should also be cleared.

Comment: Or: ``my_dic = {k: [] for k in my_dic}``.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this will only work for list objects in the dictionary?

    `for key in my_dic:
        my_dic[key] = []`

Seems for work for all types.  What is the benefits of either?

Comment: @CiaranH: the answer assumes all values are lists. Using `my_dic.update((key, []) for key in my_dic)` (or `for key in my_dic: my_dic[key] = []`, same thing really) *makes* all values lists, regardless of what type they were before.

Comment: @CiaranH: If it is an *error in your code* for any of the values to be something else then the `del value[:]` approach will expose that error. If it is *expected* that some values are not lists, then use the second approach.

Answer (score 3):

You no need to delete keys from dictionary:

```
for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

One liner:

```
my_dict =  dict.fromkeys(my_dict, None)
```

You can also replace the None type with other values that are immutable. A mutable type such as a list will cause all of the values in your new dictionary to be a reference to the same list.

For mutable types you would have to populate the dictionary with distinct instances of that type as others have shown.